# with pandas, find a max(col) row in each group

Tags: pandas

with pandas,

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `score` int)
;


INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `productName`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', '8'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', '3'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', '7'),
    (4, 'OpenDJ', '4'),
    (5, 'OpenAM', '9')
;
```

wanted result is

```
1   OpenIDM 8
3   OpenDJ  7
5   OpenAM  9
```

To get the max score on each group,

```
df.groupby('productName')['score'].max()
```

---

Result is:

```
OpenAM  9
OpenDJ  7
OpenIDM 8
```

The result is right but, I need full colmuns -> id also.
How could I get score(max) with id and productName?

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `idxmax` instead of `max`.  This way, you get the index values at which the maximums occurred.  You can then use these to access the entire row of the dataframe.

```
max_idx = df.groupby('productName', as_index=False)['score'].idxmax()

print df.loc[max_idx]

   id productName score
4   5      OpenAM     9
2   3      OpenDJ     7
0   1     OpenIDM     8
```

Comment: Thx a lot! That's what I wanted. I need to know about idmax more!